# Basic Module Tutorial or Example

Tags: modules

I am having a difficult time understanding how to output even a simple variable using a module. Ultimately I have PHP code that I need to execute to generate a PDF. I managed to do this in V2.5. I'm following all the tutorials that I can find, bu none I feel aren't clear. Any recommendations on the simplest of examples, even if it's just outputting a variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried this tutorial yet, but having learned a lot about Craft 3 from Andrew Welch's other tutorials, I don't doubt this may have some nuggets of useful information to get you on your way.

https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module

Comment: Thanks, I did see this and went through it several times, but it didn't explain how to output data into template. It's for adding a background to the login screen, just not what I need. Thank you though.

Comment: To output something into a template, you'd want to create either a Variable or a Twig Extension, just as you would for a plugin. There's a tutorial here as well: https://craftquest.io/livestreams/building-a-craft-module

Answer (score 3):

These are the pieces I needed to complete the puzzle:

- Docs for [Craft controllers](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/controllers.html)
- Docs for [Yii controllers](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers)
- Create a `FooController` class in your module
- Add a `actionBar()` method in that class
- Make sure the `$this->controllerNamespace` in your module `init` is correct
- Now, assuming your module is registered as `baz-module` in `config/app.php` then you can reach your controller with a form like

```twig
    <form method="post">
        {{ csrfInput() }}
        {{ actionInput('baz-module/foo/bar') }}
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```